# PHP Multi level array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create a list to present my product by php array.

Example:

```
Apple
 -Mac book
 -iPod
HTC
 -Mobile Phone
```

and so on...

how do I store the array like this and how do I loop it out?

well, actually this is my code.
I'm new in opencart so it's quite confuse for me.

```
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($products as $product) { $i++; 

                    $query = $this->db->query("select * from oc_product_to_category where product_id=".$product['product_id']);

                    $category_id=$query->row['category_id'];
                    $query=$this->db->query("select * from oc_category where category_id=".$category_id);

                    if($query->row['parent_id']!=0){
                    $parent_id=$query->row['parent_id'];
                    $query=$this->db->query("select * from oc_category where category_id=".$parent_id);
                    $pparent_id=$query->row['parent_id'];

                    if($pparent_id!=0){
                    $query=$this->db->query("select * from oc_category where category_id=".$pparent_id);
                    }
                    }

                   if($pparent_id!=0){
                   $query=$this->db->query("select * from oc_category_description where category_id=".$pparent_id);
                   $one=$query->row['name'];

                   $query=$this->db->query("select * from oc_category_description where category_id=".$parent_id);
                   $two=$query->row['name'];

                   $query=$this->db->query("select * from oc_category_description where category_id=".$category_id);
                   $three=$query->row['name'];


                   }
    ?>
```

My purpose is to generate a list of category that involve the manufacturer product.

Comment: Perhaps read the php documents about multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store it as

```
 $array = array("Apple"
            => array("Mac book",
                      "iPod")
              ,
             "HTC"
             =>array("Mobile Phone")
              );
```

now you can loop through it using forach(), for() or while()

```
foreach($array as $ar){
   if(is_array($ar))
   {
     foreach($ar as $sec_ar)
     {   
     echo $sec_ar;
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: how do I loop it out?

Comment: what you want to do after looping? echo or something? and which ones? all?

Comment: this will echo child item Mac book,iPod,Mobile Phone.. let me know if you want whole list or what

Answer (score 0):

```
$apple= array(

    array(
        'name'=> 'mac book',
        'cost'=>'$22',
        'color'=>'white'),  
);
```

To access it (you can use a foreach loop here) as a general example:

```
<?php echo $apple[0]['name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Review nested foreach loops...

```
foreach($food as $fruit){
  foreach($fruit as $apple){

  }
}
```

That is valid php...
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php